# Why does my website load double content? My first interactive Javascript attempt

Tags: javascript, html, css, interactive

Good day good people, I very much appreciate the depths of knowledge on this site.

Long story:

I have made a couple of very basic websites with html and css but this is my first attempt at a more interactive website with Javascript. The URL is www.audiophilesengineering.com and it has a few glitches that I cannot pinpoint in my code. Specifically, the entire "Contact" page loads the content twice. This seems like the most consistent error so I would like to tackle that first. I am currently a young broke entrepreneur, so I am forced to do most everything myself for my businesses, for now. At the same time I am dissatisfied with my previous boring website and want to make something much more interactive, but some serious glitches have developed.

tldr (short story);

Why does the content of http://audiophilesengineering.com/#!Contact.html display twice?

contact page html code:

```
<div class="genericSection section-CONTACT">
<!--add here url for this section background image-->
<img class="sectionBackgroundImage" src="pages/backgrounds/background_contact.jpg" />
<!--/section background image-->
<!--add here page number-->
<p class="pageNum textColor01">04/<span class="textColor03">07</span></p>
<!--/add here page number-->
<!--skeleton container-->
<div class="container">
    <!--Website logo-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <img class="brand" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Website logo-->
    <!--Section title H2-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <div class="h2square backgroundColor02">1</div>
            <h2 class="textColor01">Contact Us<span class="textColor02"> // Phone or Email</span></h2>
            <div class="horizontalLine backgroundColor02"></div>
            <div class="clear-fx"></div>
            <div class="addressContainer">
                      <p><a class="phoneBig textColor01" href="tel:+8134801321">813-480-1321</a></p>
                      <p><a href="mailto:audiophilesengineering@gmail.com">audiophilesengineering@gmail.com</a></p>
                      <p class="defaultText textColor01">Audiophiles Engineering<br />Tampa, Florida 33624<br />United States</p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Section title H2-->
    <!--vertical spacer-->
    <div class="verticalSpacerMedium"></div>
    <!--/vertical spacer-->
    <!--Section title H2-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <div class="h2square backgroundColor02">2</div>
            <h2 class="textColor01">Visit Us<span class="textColor02"> // By Appointment Only</span></h2>
            <div class="horizontalLine backgroundColor02"></div>
            <div class="clear-fx"></div>
            <!--full width map-->
            <div class="mapContainer">
                <iframe width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=28.04,-82.51&amp;sll=28.040078,-82.510190&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=p&amp;ll=28.033198,-82.507324&amp;spn=1.939406,8.789063&amp;z=6&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Section title H2-->
</div>
<!--/skeleton container-->
</div>
```

Comment: shows only single time to me.

Comment: Only displays once for me. May I ask what browser you are using?

Comment: I use Firefox 27.0.1 but my wife uses Safari 6.1 and has the same double content display.

edit:
Okay I see, it works correctly directly from the link. Try going to the "Contact" page from the "Home" page http://audiophilesengineering.com/#!Home.html

Comment: @AudiophilesEngineering Yeah I tried that. It's strange. What is seems like is happening is the Javascript is appending your content to the body causing it to duplicate. I'm not big on interactive pages but that's just a guess.

Comment: I also only see it once. Mind telling us which of your many many JavaScript files actually loads the content?